# Como alterar o idioma do R?

Tags: r, windows

Ao instalar o [r](/questions/tagged/r) em minha maquina percebi que os menus e as saídas do console estavam todas em português.

Como faço para alterar para inglês? Dentro do `RGui` não encontrei nenhuma opção para alterar o idioma e não é possível reinstalar o [r](/questions/tagged/r) em minha maquina (ambiente corporativo e não tenho acesso Administrador local).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vá para a pasta em que o R foi instalado que deve ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entre na pasta `etc` e edite o arquivo `RConsole`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mude a linha que começa com `language =` e coloque `language = en`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como o R está instalado no arquivo de programas, não consegui editar esse arquivo por questões de permissão do filesystem. Consegui de outra maneira aqui, vou esperar mais um tempo para ver se aparecem mais respostas.

Comment: @gmsantos Tudo que você precisa é iniciar o notepad (ou outro editor de texto) como administrador pra ter permissão de editar os arquivos. A resposta de Daniel é a correta.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro estou em *um ambiente corporativo e não tenho acesso Administrador na minha maquina local*.

Comment: Tem o comando `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE = "en")` também, mas comigo nem sempre funciona.

Answer (score 3):

Outras duas formas de alterar o idioma do `R` são:

1. Executar o comando abaixo no console do `R`, em seguida fechar e abrir novamente (aqui funcionou assim)

   ```
   Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE = "en")
   ```
2. Adicionar ao atalho do `R` o argumento `LANGUAGE = EN`

   [image: Propriedades do Atalho]